# Flutter web TextField does not display text written on the keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Flutter web TextField does not display the text written on the keyboard when I use the package.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart'.

the textfield works, but when I use:

import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart'.

the textfield doesn't display anything while I'm writing on the keyboard.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
   body: Container(
    child: TextField(
      controller: controller,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

`version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.7.3
  build_web_compilers: ^2.8.0
dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui`

when I change the css of the input, that I put the transparent color to color #333 it displays its :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `flutter_web`

**This repository is no longer maintained**. 
As of September 10, 2019, Flutter for web development has fully moved to https://github.com/flutter/flutter. 
To build web apps using Flutter use the standard Flutter SDK.

Comment: When I use it this way I have this problem.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672179/flutter-for-web-text-cut-off-at-bottom